# UISlider doesn't move when its parent UIView's location is set?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uislider

I have a UIView called `volumeControlView` which gets created when this action is called:

```
@IBAction func toggleRainControl(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.addSubview(volumeControlView)
    //volumeControlView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100)
    volumeControlView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    volumeSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi/2))
}
```

Inside of `volumeControlView` I have a UISlider called `volumeSlider`. It's supposed to adjust the volume of my rain sound effect when touched. When the user touches the `volumeSlider`, this action is called:

```
@IBAction func changeRainVolume(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let selectedValue = Double(sender.value)
    player.rainPlayer.volume = selectedValue
}
```

This all works perfectly when the commented-out line in toggleRainControl() is commented out, but when I try to adjust the position of `volumeControlView` by uncommenting that line, it breaks the UISlider functionality and it no longer moves when the user touches it. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I updated toggleRainControl() to this:

```
@IBAction func toggleRainControl(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.addSubview(volumeControlView)
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y - 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 100)
    volumeControlView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    volumeSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi/2))
}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: The blue part is the frame of volumeControlView]

The blue part is the frame of volumeControlView

Comment: On your commented out line your are sending the y:-100 you are sending the view outside of the patented bounds. So essentially it’s out of view and cannot detect you touch events.

Comment: I changed my toggleRainControl() action so that when it is called the volumeControlView frame increases to accomodate the uislider and now the slider is fully inside volumeControlView's frame, but I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure user interaction isEnabled on the volume controlView??

Comment: yes. and the uislider does work when it is positioned in the bottom half of volumeControlView's frame

Comment: Are you adding the slider to volume control via storyboard or code?

Comment: It must be an issue with your view hierarchy.

Comment: its added via storyboard

Comment: You might have the timer on-top of the slider after your rotation

Comment: The view hierarchy is main view > container view > audioPlayerViewController > volumeControlView and the UISlider is inside volumeControlView. I just realized as I was typing this, could it be because I have a container view that isn't large enough?

Comment: Ofcourse it can be if you clip the containers subview and your subview disappear then I guess you need to adjust the containers frame to detect touches